# MS SQL Server error message log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have bunch of stored procedure in my database and some of those SP include RAISERROR in it.
Is SQL Server logs these exception(User defined/System) somewhere?
If yes is it possible to query these messages and error numbers?

Comment: I guess this would help you out
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/05/26/how-it-works-sql-server-engine-exception-handling.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I have just checked the path as per the blog and couldn't find specified file in it.
Following are the files I found in my SQL Server Log directory(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SERVER\MSSQL\Log)
ERRORLOG
ERRORLOG.1,
ERRORLOG.2,
FDLAUNCHERRORLOG,
FDLAUNCHERRORLOG.1,
log.trc,

Comment: If you want to check what the original location that messages are stored in, you need to run the following query:

`select * from sys.messages`
This works in 2005 not sure about the rest

Comment: In fact it I had gone through the table sys.messages and it doesn't serve the purpose.I am actually looking for the errors occurred while executing my SP since I am NOT loging errors thrown by RAISEERROR function  
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649.aspx

Comment: Refer to this :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38991/A-Closer-Look-Inside-RAISERROR-SQLServer-2005

Answer (score 0):

These are not logged automatically but you can use [xp_logevent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx) to add all errors to error log manually.

Here is an example from MSDN

```
DECLARE @@TABNAME varchar(30)
DECLARE @@USERNAME varchar(30)
DECLARE @@MESSAGE varchar(255)
SET @@TABNAME = 'customers'
SET @@USERNAME = USER_NAME()
SELECT @@MESSAGE = 'The table ' + @@TABNAME + ' is not owned by the user 
   ' + @@USERNAME + '.'

USE master
EXEC xp_logevent 60000, @@MESSAGE, informational
```

You’ll need to modify all stored procedures so that may be a downside but it will